# Dependency not injected into class by Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, windsor-3.0

I have the following interfaces and base class.

**UserRespository:**

```
public class UserRepository : Repository<User>, IUserRepository
{
    public IAuthenticationContext authenticationContext;

    public UserRepository(IAuthenticationContext authenticationContext)
        :base(authenticationContext as DbContext)  { }

    public User GetByUsername(string username)
    {
        return authenticationContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username == username);
    }
}
```

**UserService:**

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public UserService(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> GetAll()
    {
        return _userRepository.GetAll();
    }

    public User GetByUsername(string username)
    {
        return _userRepository.GetByUsername(username);
    }
}
```

Now when I inject the UserService it's _userRepository is null.
Any idea what I need to configure to get it to inject the repository correctly.

**I have the following install code:**

```
public class RepositoriesInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Types.FromAssemblyNamed("DataAccess")
            .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Repository") && !type.IsInterface)
            .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
            .Configure(c =>c.LifestylePerWebRequest()));

        //AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext();
    }
}

public class ServicesInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Types.FromAssemblyNamed("Services")
            .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Service") && !type.IsInterface)
            .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
            .Configure(c => c.LifestylePerWebRequest()));
    }
}
```

**How would I go about registering the concrete DbContext's**

```
public class AuthenticationContext : DbContext
{
    public AuthenticationContext() : base("name=Authentication")
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

When I remove the default constructor in UserService I get the following error:

> Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.HandlerException: Can't create component 'DataAccess.Repositories.UserRepository' as it has dependencies to be satisfied. 'DataAccess.Repositories.UserRepository' is waiting for the following dependencies: - Service 'DataAccess.AuthenticationContext' which was not registered.

Comment: Have you tried removing the default constructor from `UserService`? Having multiple constructors [is an anti-pattern](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).

Comment: If I remove the constructor the UserService won't be injected into my controller.

Comment: So what is the error you get when you remove the default constructor?

Comment: Which constructor did you remove?

Comment: I updated my post. I remove the default constructor in the UserService. How can I register concrete implementations of the DbContext?

Comment: Please update your question with how your UserService is right now.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because I didn't have default constructor in the class that implements the Interface

Answer (score 1):

For those looking at this question later, also please make sure that the name of the implementing class starts with the interface name.

ex:

`class FooBarImpl : IFooBar`

NOT

`class Foo : ISomething`

Answer (score 0):

Based off your exception in your "UPDATE" you need to register your AuthenticationContext class so Windsor knows how to create it.

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<AuthenticationContext>()
        .ImplementedBy<AuthenticationContext>());
```

However, based off the UserRepository.cs code it depends on the interface IAuthenticationContext (and not AuthenticationContext) so you would specify the implementation of the interface:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IAuthenticationContext>()
        .ImplementedBy<AuthenticationContext>());
```